# How to avoid mixed content trying to upload an image

Tags: laravel, vue.js, tinymce

"I am trying to upload an image with tinyMce , but keep getting mixed content error, i know its because its trying to make an api call with 'http://' instead of https:// , the issue is i don't know where to fix this." i have tried everything i can think of , please i am new to laravel and vue and this is my first time using tinymce editor.
This is the error message :
"Mixed Content: The page at 'https://bizguruh.com/admin/add/product/117/ARTICLES' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://bizguruh.com/api/image-upload'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."

```
<app-editor 
                     :init="{
                         plugins: 'advlist autolink lists link image imagetools charmap print preview anchor textcolor insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount',

                             toolbar: 'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat |image help',
                             image_title: true,

                        height: 300,


                        images_upload_url: '/api/image-upload/',

                        file_picker_types: 'image',
                        automatic_uploads:false,
                        relative_urls:false,
                       convert_urls:false,
                        file_picker_callback:function(callback, value, meta) {
                              loadFile(callback, value)        

                    }, }" class="form-control" v-model="product.articles.description">
                    </app-editor>

 loadFile(cb,mt){
              if (mt.filetype === 'image') {
                              let up = this.$refs.upload


                          up.onchange = function() {
                        let file = this.files[0];
                        let reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onload = (e)=> {
                           let id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
                            let blobCache =  tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
                            let base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
                            let blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
                            blobCache.add(blobInfo);

                     /* call the callback and populate the Title field with the file name */
                        cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
                        };
                        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                        }

                        up.click()


                    }



   public function imageUpload(Request $request){

       $file = $request->file('file');


      $path= url('images/').'/'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
    $imgpath = $file->move(public_path('images/'),$file->getClientOriginalName());
    $fileNameToStore = $path;

    return json_encode(['location' => $fileNameToStore]); 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
images_upload_url: '/api/image-upload/'
```

with

```
images_upload_url: '{{ secure_url('api/image-upload') }}'
```

It will force to produce a, well, [secured URL](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-secure-url).
The same applies to

```
$path= secure_url('images/').'/'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can i write this in the template, it keeps giving me an error if i put it this way

Comment: it's in a vue template